# Как к jDateChooser применить DefaultFormatterFactory

Tags: java, swing

На панели есть jDateChooser, есть готовый метод возвращающий DefaultFormatterFactory, как его применить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку jDateChooser составной компанент:

```
JFormattedTextField dat = (JFormattedTextField) jDateChooser.getDateEditor();
dat.setFormatterFactory(getDateFormatterFactory());

public static DefaultFormatterFactory getDateFormatterFactory() throws ParseException{
   MaskFormatter dateFormatter = new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");
   dateFormatter.setValidCharacters("0123456789");
   dateFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
   dateFormatter.setValueClass(String.class);
   DefaultFormatterFactory dateFormatterFactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(dateFormatter);
   return dateFormatterFactory;
}
```